# В чем заключается основная задача токена, и стоит ли расшифровывать токен на фронте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jwt

С сервера я посылаю токен с данными о пользователе - логин, никнейм, фотка и т.д. Но стоит ли вообще шифровать таким образом данные о пользователе? Или отправлять пользователя в месте с запросом входа в акаунт?

Пример 1:
Пользователь входит в аккаунт и ему запросом отправляется токен вместе с фоткой,никнеймом, которые в последствии передаются в redux

Пример 2:
Пользователь входит в аккаунт и ему запросом отправляется только токен, токен дешифруется и данные которые хранятся в токене передаются в redux.

Стоит ли делать дешифрацию токена на фронте, если нет , то что передавать в токен с сервера?
Если да, то какие данные можно передавать вместе с токеном, потому что некоторые сервера отправляют вместе с токеном, например, почту. В таком случае почему они не закидывают почту в токен?

Эта тема для меня не понятна, сколько я не искал ответа в инете.

Comment: Токен используется для идентификации и аутентификации пользователя (и иногда авторизации). Если ваша система не использует логин-никнейм-фотку-почту для проверки подлинности пользователя, то значит нечего им делать в токене

Comment: @andreymal То есть, если пользователь входит на моем сайте по логину и паролю, то в токене я должен передавать лишь логин пользователя, так как он всегда уникален и не может быть одинаковым?

Comment: Если логин также гарантированно никогда не может измениться, то видимо да

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю за разъяснения!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте начнем с видов токена.

Существует 3 основных вида токенов: токен идентификации, токен доступа и токен обновления (`Refresh Token`).

Токен идентификации используется только приложением. Такие токены не должны использоваться для доступа к `API`. Каждый токен идентификации содержит информацию, предназначенную для определенной аудитории (`audience`), которой обычно является адресат (получатель, `recipient`) токена.

Согласно спецификации [**OpenID Connect**](https://openid.net/connect/) аудиторией токена идентификации (указанной в настройке aud) должен быть идентификатор клиента (`client ID`), выполняющего запрос на аутентификацию. Если это не так, токен считается не заслуживающим доверия. Наличие идентификатора клиента означает, что только данный клиент должен потреблять (`consume`) этот токен.

Токен доступа используется для уведомления `API` о том, что его предъявитель (`bearer`) имеет доступ к API, т. е. выполнил все необходимые действия (в соответствии со сферами доступа — `scopes`).

Токены доступа не должны использоваться для аутентификации. Обычно в такой токен включается только идентификатор клиента (настройка `sub`).

Токен обновления, как следует из названия, используется для обновления токена доступа без принуждения пользователя к повторной аутентификации, т.е. автоматически.

**Правила использования токенов**

Общие рекомендации по использованию токенов могут быть сведены к следующему:

- секретность означает безопасность: ключ, используемый для подписания токена, должен быть скрытым;
- токен не должен содержать чувствительных данных пользователя;
- токен должен иметь ограниченное время жизни (`expiration`): технически после подписания токен является валидным до тех пор, пока не изменится ключ, использованный для его подписания, или пока не истечет время его жизни;
- для передачи токена должно использоваться только `HTTPS`-соединение: в противном случае, токен может быть перехвачен и скомпрометирован;
- при необходимости для проверки токенов должна использоваться вторичная система верификации;
- с целью уменьшения количества запросов к серверу следует предусмотреть возможность временного хранения токенов на стороне клиента (в куки или на sessionStorage, но не на localStorage)